# mod_wsgi vs matplotlib - cannot import matplotlib.cbook

Tags: python, django, apache, matplotlib, mod-wsgi

So I see this question in a couple places on google, but can't find a working answer anywhere.

Matplotlib and mod_wsgi are butting heads. I'm writing a plotting django application, and on the django lightweight server everything runs great, but as soon as I launch it to a real server the following issues arise:

The first is the MPLCONFIGDIR to a writable directory, which there are plenty of answers online. Just for now I just set my directory to writable, the one it was trying to access.

Then as soon as that is fixed I get a cannot import matplotlib.cbook error. I have no idea how to get rid of this. I can import matplotlib.cbook in python command line, just whenever it goes through the web I can't do it.

Comment: did you find any answers? and what directory did you end up using for MPLCONFIGDIR?

Comment: Well this sucks... please tell me it's 2016 and we have a solution to this?